# Cplex 12.10: How can I solve an LP relaxation?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, cplex, lp-relaxation

I have an `IloCplex` object which contains a MILP. 
Is there a way to obtain the objective value of its LP relaxation, without having to rewrite the entire model as an LP?

Comment: You can add an IloConversion of each variable to you IloModel object, and then solve the resulting model using a corresponding IloCplex object. In OPL you can run the covertAllIntVars() function on your OPL model and then solve the resulting model. I am almost sure that there is no equivalent to this function in Java or C++.

Comment: @Sune: you should make this an answer.

Answer (score 8):

Based on @prubin's instigation, I have turned my comment into an answer:
You can add an IloConversion of each variable to you IloModel object, and then solve the resulting model using a corresponding IloCplex object. In OPL you can run the covertAllIntVars() function on your OPL model and then solve the resulting model. I am almost sure that there is no equivalent to this function in Java or C++.

You can only add one IloConversion of a variable to a model, implying that you cannot add a conversion from ILOBOOL/ILOINT to ILOFLOAT, and then convert the LP relaxation back to a MIP by adding another IloConversion from ILOFLOAT to ILOBOOL/ILOINT. However, you can remove the first IloConversion by invoking the end() method on the corresponding IloExtractable.
For more information, you can check this link https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.5.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/refcppopl/html/classes/IloConversion.html

Answer (score 3):

I think the standard method is to stop just after the root node has been solved.
For example, using the C++ API:

```
// Uncomment the following line to disable CPLEX cuts:
// cplex.setParam(IloCplex::NumParam::CutsFactor, 0.0);

cplex.setParam(IloCplex::IntParam::NodeLim, 0);
cplex.solve();

const auto linear_relaxation_obj = cplex.getBestObjValue();

// If you want to continue solving the MILP via branch-and-bound:
// cplex.setParam(IloCplex::NumParam::CutsFactor, -1.0);
cplex.setParam(IloCplex::IntParam::NodeLim, 999999999);

if(cplex.solve()) {
    // Fully solved the MILP
}
```

Setting `NodeLim` to `0` means CPLEX will stop after the root node is fully explored.
Setting it to `1` will also perform branching and select the next node to explore.

Setting `CutsFactor` to a value between `0.0` and `1.0`, CPLEX won't generate any cuts, thereby solving the linear relaxation of your original model.
With `CutsFactor` at its default value `-1.0`, or at a value strictly larger than `1.0`, CPLEX might add cuts at the root node, thus giving a tighter dual bound that you might have if solving the linear relaxation of the model.

Comment: Does CPLEX terminate after the first time the root node is solved, or just before it starts branching? There is a layer of cuts added in between those two.

Comment: My understanding is that the root node is fully explored, including adding the cuts. I edited the answer.

Comment: I thought so. It means that this method doesn't really solve the LP relaxation of the model extracted. So, if you want to compare the strength of a model, you have to be careful.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. On the other hand, solving with all variables IloFloat doesn't add cuts?

Comment: No. When solving an LP (all variables declared as ILOFLOAT) no cuts are added, as this would indeed change the logic of the model.

Comment: Good point, I edited the answer again. I still think this method should be easier to implement, compared to looping through all variables and changing their type (potentially twice, if you then want to keep solving the MILP). Also, using this method you are not solving the root node twice.

Comment: I think, in some sense, you are right. However, yet another thing you need to be aware of is that the presolve performs a lot of presolve reduction and tightening on a MIP, which it cannot do on an LP. Basically, it utilizes the logical implications from binary and integer variables in order to strengthen the formulation. Thus, using a node limit *does not* lead to a solution of the LP relaxation, but to a solution of a presolved, reduced and cut enhanced relaxation of the original model.

Comment: Again, you're right. I mean, you could also disable `Cplex::Params::Preprocessing::Presolve`, `IloCplex::Param::Preprocessing::Relax`, and `IloCplex::Param::Preprocessing::Reduce`, but then maybe it's really easier to flip all variables to continuous.

Answer (score 2):

I want to expand on @Sunes answer, as I too wanted to solve the LP relaxation of my MIP and thought, there must be another solution than to convert each variable manually (at least this is how I interpreted @Sunes answer and it sounded needlessly complex). Therefore, I unnecessarily used up a lot more time searching through the internet for alternatives (without success).

It happens that you can convert a whole `IloNum/Int/BoolVarArray` at once and using IloConversion is way simpler than it sounds. Assuming you have your MIP model in an IloModel `model` and that you have all your integer variables in an array `y`. Then creating the LP relaxation of your MIP is as easy as

```
IloConversion relax_y = IloConversion( env, y, ILOFLOAT );
model.add( relax_y );
```

To regain the original MIP model just execute

```
relax_y.end();
```